# Installation Error with CouchDB

Tags: installation, couchdb

I tried to install like this:

```
./configure --with-erlang=/home/cgenesis/erlang/usr/local/lib/erlang/usr/include --disable-dependency-tracking
make
```

But this is all i get:

```
./couch_key_tree.erl:78: type boolean() undefined
./couch_key_tree.erl:79: type boolean() undefined
./couch_key_tree.erl:93: type boolean() undefined
./couch_key_tree.erl:136: type boolean() undefined
```

Comment: Do you see this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1048 ?